# Why does $x^2 \equiv 2 \pmod{5}$ have no solution?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, quadratic-residues

Can someone explain why $x^2 \equiv 2 \pmod{5}$ has no solution other than trial and error?

So I've shown that modulo 5, we have $0^2 \equiv 0, 1^2 \equiv 1, 2^2 \equiv 4, 3^2 \equiv 4, 4^2 \equiv 1$ and I'm seeing that it doesn't look like there is a solution but what is the actual reason? Since I can't go through infinitely many numbers.

Comment: What sort of "reason" are you hoping for?  For an odd prime $p$, $2$ is a square $\pmod p$ iff $p\equiv \pm 1 \pmod 8$.  See, e.g., [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_reciprocity).

Comment: Are you familiar with the theory of quadratic residues ? It is well known that $2$ is a quadratic residue of some odd prime $p$ , if and only if $p$ is of the form $8k\pm 1$.

Comment: Is there a rule if 2 and 5 are relatively prime there is no solution? (I know that's not true but just an example) I'm just trying to see how I would justify why it has no solution other than being told by someone that it doesn't have one?

Comment: Trial and error is a perfectly good method!  In general, with large numbers, best is usually to use Quadratic Reciprocity.

Comment: so I can say x^$2$≡3(mod 5) also doesn't have a solution by trial and error, however x^$2$≡6(mod 5)would because6(mod 5)=1(mod 5) and 4$^2$=16≡1(mod 5)

Comment: @Peter Can the same also hold for x$^2$≡3(mod 5) by saying 3 is not of the form 8k+/-1 or is that strictly for the number 2?

Comment: To answer the other question : It is enough to check all the numbers $0$ upto $n-1$ , since the congruence keeps holding/not holding , if we choose another $x$ with the same residue modulo $n$.

Comment: @Peter ah okay because testing 7 for instance would have been the same as 2 (mod5)?

Comment: @Lil yes correct

Comment: @Peter Thank you! One last thing- can I say x^2≡6(mod 5)would have a solution because 6(mod 5)=1(mod 5) and 4$^2$=16≡1(mod 5)

Comment: Yes, we can reduce the right side modulo $5$.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: For residue $3$, there is another rule. Study the reciprocity law (hope I spelled it correctly). My rule above only holds for residue $2$

Answer (score 1):

Yes, because every integer is of one of the forms:
$$5k,5k\pm1, 5k\pm2, k\in\Bbb Z$$
and we get:

$$(5k)^2=25k^2\equiv0\pmod5$$
$$(5k\pm1)^2=25k^2\pm10k+1\equiv1\pmod5$$
$$(5k\pm2)^2=25k^2\pm20k+4\equiv4\pmod5$$

None of these are $\equiv2\pmod5$, so no solutions exist

Answer (score 1):

You have already shown what you need. Every integer is of the form $0, 1, 2, 3$, or $4$ modulo $5$, and  $0^2$ mod $5 = 0$, $1^2$ mod $5 = 1$, $2^2$ mod $5 = 4$, $3^2$ mod $5 = 4$, and $4^2$ mod $5 = 1$, so we know that there is no integer $x$ for which $x^2 \equiv 2(mod\;5)$ i.e. $x^2(mod\;5) \neq 2$ for all integers $x$.

Answer (score 0):

Since there are only 5 elements in ${\mathbb Z}_5$, we can just try all 5 of them:
$0^2=0, 1^2=1, 2^2=4, 3^2=9\equiv 4\pmod{5}, 4^2=16\equiv 1 \pmod{5}$. So none of them when squared gives us $2 \pmod{5}$

Answer (score 0):

Well every integer ends with 0 or 1 or 2 or...or 9.

So $x^2$ ends with 0 or 1 or 4 or 5 or 6 or 9,

so $x^2$ cannot be 2 modulo 5.